# WPF - Floating Toolbar

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms

How can I make a floating toolbar (like the mini font floating toolbar in Word 2007) using WPF? I would like it to appear and disappear from mouse movement over items.

Thanks

Q

Answer (score 6):

Look into the [Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx) control.

Answer (score 0):

You could go the tricky way, creating a form with no border.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following [popup samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771558(VS.85).aspx).